# Running Android emulator on another computer

Tags: android, android-studio, arm

I was wondering if there was a way to run an Android emulator on another computer than the one I'm coding / building the app from. I have a very nice computer with good components and I want to code and build from it, but I don't have an Intel CPU, which means I cannot use VT-x. Therefore, I'm trying to launch the ARM emulator, but after waiting for about 5 minutes, it still wasn't launched (the android booting screen was still shown).

Therefore, I'd like for my computer to deploy the application on my laptop's Android emulator, because it has an Intel processor. I'm coding in Android Studio. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks a lot,
Ferdz

Comment: @codeMagic sorry, but that doesn't actually answer my question. I know about ARM, I just want to run from a device to another

Comment: I think I misunderstood. Anyway, [this post might help](http://www.41post.com/5003/programming/android-adb-remote-emulator-access) *disclaimer: I didn't read through it*

Comment: @stuntmania just use genymotion

Comment: @has19 I never heard about that, but it looks great. How well does it run on AMD processors?

Comment: Yes there is a way, would anyone like me to answer it?